# Are methods that update multiple entities not typically part of a DAO?

Tags: design-patterns, dao, oop

I've seen a million examples of DAOs, and for the most part they all implement your basic CRUD operations for single entities, with maybe a few methods that return lists (e.g. List getCustomers()).

However, I've never seen an example in which there is a method that updates, deletes, or creates multiple entities, like: void update(List).

Are methods that update multiple entities not typically part of a DAO, or are they just not often used in examples? I've got a requirement in which I've got to do some batch inserting, and calling myDAO.create() a hundred times isn't terribly efficient.

I just want to make sure I'm not missing something before I go ahead and do what seems obvious.

Answer (score 2):

I find that batch updates are usually done with tools provided by the database vendor.

I agree that the DAOs that I've seen usually don't have methods for create/update/delete overloaded to take List, but there's no reason why they can't.

The one thought that brings me up short is that DAOs don't own transactions when I write them.  They can never know where they're part of a larger unit of work.  That's what services do.

My advice would be to leave the DAOs alone and let a separate service layer own the batch operations.  Services own the transaction logic.  It's also a good place to include logic for "chunking" a large update into pieces.  That lets you checkpoint the batch  and keep the size of your rollback logs manageable.

Comment: Hm, it seems like I would still have to have in my DAO a method that can take a list so that I could implement a proper batch update.  I could still split the batch up in my service method and have it all run under the same transaction, yes?

Comment: No, I'm suggesting that DAO would still take a single object instance, and service would call DAO in a loop (or loops if you're "chunking" it).  The service method would be a single unit of work that would own the transaction.  The service might also batch the transaction to cut down on the network traffic.

Comment: How would that work?  If I were using Jdbc, for example, I wouldn't be able to use executeBatch in the service... I would basically be committing a whole bunch of regular updates.

Comment: You'd set auto commit to false, accumulate all the updates into a JDBC batch, execute the batch, the commit or rollback as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the examples don´t use it often. My DAOs have methods to access, create and update both single entities and collections of records.

Answer (score 0):

`void update(List)` should act the same as `void update(Item)`, only the `List` one would update multiple items. If not, it should be unless there are very specific reasons why not to. The overhead of calling a method is not a concern if they do the same thing.

For example, calling `update(Item)` 1000 times vs calling `update(List)` 1 and it does the same as `update(Item)` only a 1000 times means there will be very little performance difference.

Comment: If I was to implement an update(List) method, I wouldn't have it do an update(Item) for each item in the list.  I would use whatever batch update methods my database layer provides.  The overhead of 1000 separate updates can be much higher than a single batch update at that level.